# External Modules Freeze after Declaring a Windows Form in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, module

I have a script that automates the creation of Sharepoint sites for my company and I've found that it kept freezing. I've narrowed it down to some interaction between the following lines:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$progress = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
connect-exchangeOnline
```

If the code is run in the order above, the program freezes.
If the code is run in the order below, it works perfectly:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
connect-exchangeonline
$progress = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
```

The same thing occurs when replacing `connect-exchangeonline` with `Register-SPMTMigration -migratewithoutrootfolder -force`. I thought maybe the command was the issue but it seems to be accessing any external module.

When debuging, I find it reaches the `connect-exchangeonline` line but then immediately hangs upon entering that module

I've tried this with the same result on multiple machines.

Unfortunately, I can't just move the problematic lines up so if anyone has any thoughts that would be greatly appreciated

ETA: This is not my entire script, however, the issue occurs even if I run just these three lines in a separate console, so I know it has to be some issue in this snippet alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you omitted some script there, and your actually loading up a Windows Form GUI, as if your trying to do something like show progress on the GUI, and Connect to exchange, you would need to use Jobs or Runspaces, as the thread cant do both connect and update the GUI at the same time.

ps I dont have a enough RP to comment for clarifications yet, hence why this is an answer.

Comment: I added this is the original post, but, while the three lines are part of a larger script, the error happens with just those three lines in a separate console

Comment: Just had a go on my computer, and it freezes too, this looks like a bug to me, it will be when its trying to load the embedded web view for the authentication, and loading system.Windows.Forms.Form is somehow interfering with it. 
Good thing though is PowerShell 7 doesnt use the same embedded web view PowerShell 5 does, so if you run this PS7 it works, and authenticates via your web browser instead.

I cant seem to find a repo for this module for some reason, I can only find a help docs page, so I'm not sure where to report the bug.

Comment: You are a miracle worker. I didn't think to try it on PS7. I was banging my head against the wall. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out!!